# Selecting an item (from a set of items) based on distance and frequency of occurence

Tags: python, algorithm

There exists a set of points (or items, it doesn't matter). Each point `a` is at a specific distance from other points in the set. The distance can be retrieved via the function `retrieve_dist(a, b)`.

This question is about programming (in Python) an algorithm to pick a point, with replacement, from this set of points. The picked point:

i) has to be at the maximum possible distance from all already-selected points, while adhering to the requirement in (ii)

ii) the number of times an already-selected point occurs in the sample must carry weight in this calculation. I.e. more frequently-selected points should be weighed more heavily.

E.g. imagine `a` and `b` have already been selected (100 and 10 times respectively). Then when the next point is to be selected, it's distance from `a` matters more than its distance from `b`, in line with the frequency of occurrence of `a` in the already-selected sample.

---

**What I can try:**

This would have been easy to accomplish if weights/frequencies weren't in play. I could do:

```
distances = defaultdict(int)
for new_point in set_of_points:
    for already_selected_point in selected_points:
        distances[new_point] += retrieve_dist(new_point, already_selected_point)
```

Then I'd sort `distances.items()` by the second entry in each tuple, and would get the desired item to select.

However, when frequencies of already-selected points come into play, I just can't seem to wrap my head around this problem.

Can an expert help out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `selected_points`?  Is it a `set` or a `list`? If it is a `list` I don't think you need to do anything, as you would automatically consider all `a`s and all `b`s as they would repeat in the `selected_points` list.

Comment: @JohanL: In my mind, it was a `set`, but I see what you mean :-) Let me quickly get back to you on this - meanwhile, you could put that directly as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution to your problem would be to make `selected_points` a `list` rather than a `set`. In this case, each new point is compared to `a` and `b` (and all other points) as many times as they have already been found.

If each point is typically found many times, it might be possible to improve perfomance using a `dict` instead, with the key being the points, and the value being the number of times each point is selected. In that case I think your algorithm would be

```
distances = defaultdict(int)

for new_point in set_of_points:
    for already_selected_point, occurances in selected_points.items():
        distances[new_point] += occurances * retrieve_dist(new_point, already_selected_point)
```

Comment: Ultimately, the problem with this approach was that the item with the highest weighted distance ended up solely dictating the outcome. The weightage of other already selected items were ignored.